# Loading Message using jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this loading message while my ajax call retrieves the data.  But I'm getting strange results.  Either the message appears and half way renders until ajax finishes or it doest appear at all leaving the user wondering what is wrong.  The reason I need a loading message is its about a 5-10 sec delay while the data is retrieved the dialog box is opened the map is drawn then the feature layer of the map is redrawn with labels.

Here is my code:

```
function loadData(v) 
{       
    var reg = 1; 
    var vId = v;                       
    var d =
    {
        regionType: reg,
        varId: vId
    };

    //$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    //    $(this).show();
    //}).ajaxStop(function () {
    //    $(this).hide();
    //});

    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).show();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: WebRoot + "ws/bis.asmx/Data",
        data: d,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {                

            fipsData = data.d;
            openBox(d); 
            init(regType, varId);

            $("#loading").ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });

        } //ends success function
    });  //ends ajax call         
}; //ends message
```

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to wrap your `hide()` call in an `ajaxStop()` method - you're using the success function, so unless your `openBox` or `init` methods are making ajax calls, you can just call `hide` at the last line of your success function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the `ajaxStart` or `ajaxStop`

```
function loadData(v) 
{       
    var reg = 1; 
    var vId = v; 
    var $loading = $("#loading");                      
    var d =
    {
        regionType: reg,
        varId: vId
    };


    // Starts immediately after this line so no need to use ajaxStart
    $loading.show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: WebRoot + "ws/bis.asmx/Data",
        data: d,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {                

            fipsData = data.d;
            openBox(d); 
            init(regType, varId);

        }, //ends success function

        // Fires even if a failure, so loading spinner won't hang around for no reason
        done: function() {
          $loading.hide();
        }
    });  //ends ajax call         
}; //ends message
```

Comment: My original answer was using `$(this)` by mistake when I believe you intended that to mean `#loading`

Comment: Yes works pretty well now I just have to smooth it out and position the loading message and background thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're set on using `ajaxStop` and `ajaxStart`, then you should move the `ajaxStop` handler outside of the success callback.

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: WebRoot + "ws/bis.asmx/Data",
        data: d,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {                

            fipsData = data.d;
            openBox(d); 
            init(regType, varId);

        } //ends success function
    });  //ends ajax call
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is "this"

```
$.ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").show();
});
```

"this" variable changes depend on how your function being called.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

above link can be a good start to learn more about js function calls!